# What use does the ID have in style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So my question is:

Why should I give a class / id to a style tag (I suppose in order to identify it, of course), what use can I give the ID / class that style tag is taking? Is it useful for something? Because Twitter identifies the user custom style with an ID.

Maybe jQuery interaction or something?

```
<style class="hello" id="id">
...
</style>
```

Comment: Do you mean "`<style class="someClass" ...>`?? There's no use in that.

Comment: This question is pretty vague.  ID/Class attribute is not required on a style element.  But if a developer needs to get to that style element to do something out of the ordinary, then they would do that. Personally, I've never seen such hacks.

Comment: @Pathachiever11 Twitter does it, that's why I ask it.

Comment: You'd give a style element an id or a class for exactly the same reasons that you would give any other element an id or a class.

Comment: @KaiQing I don't mean that. Please don't sub estimate me. Look at my question carefully.

Comment: @wonderwhy There could be a hundred reasons behind it. You can go through their JS to figure out what they're doing.  Generally speaking, this is not good practice.  Maybe they might be using at a stylizer?  Swap out the style tag to update theme or something? Idk.  Could be lots of reasons.  Or maybe just a label for the purpose of the style/script tag.

Comment: Ok thanks that was kinda what I was trying to know.

Comment: @wonderwhy Yeah, its pure speculation at this point. Unless someone from Twitter comments, we may never know why "they" do it. =)

Comment: You can use it to "remove" the tag if you want that css not to apply anymore.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde yeah that's another use. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's an example of why you might want to access a `<style>` element](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/KLxJm).  The HTMLStyleElement API includes a "disabled" property which, if set to `true`, disables the whole thing. The JavaScript code in that Codepen is just

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
  $('#colorstyle').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

There are *rare* occasions that call for CSS rules to be manipulated directly. An example of that would be preprocessors like [Less](http://lesscss.org/). In such cases, being able to find (or exclude) `<style>` elements by a particular class would be useful.

Comment: Thanks guy! Now I see it, it is truly useful. I may use it in the future now I know it.